# Set max lines on StaticLayout

Tags: android

`StaticLayout.Builder` was introduced in API 23 and I want to target lower. How do I set the maximum number of lines using the original constructors for `StaticLayout`?

The properties on the reference all seem to be read only.

Answer (score 1):

In the StaticLayout class after API 22, there is still a hidden constructor that takes many parameters:

```
 /**
  * @hide
  * @deprecated Use {@link Builder} instead.
  */
 @Deprecated
 public StaticLayout(CharSequence source, int bufstart, int bufend,
                     TextPaint paint, int outerwidth,
                     Alignment align, TextDirectionHeuristic textDir,
                     float spacingmult, float spacingadd,
                     boolean includepad,
                     TextUtils.TruncateAt ellipsize, int ellipsizedWidth,
                     int maxLines)
```

As you can see, the last parameter is the max number of lines.

Comment: @IanWarburton Could you please confirmed the question is closed and potentially mark it as solved ? Regards

Comment: constructor is hidden and not available

Answer (score 1):

This constructor is hidden and it seems no way to use it with older APIs. I even tried to set private field `mMaximumVisibleLineCount` using reflection, but with no luck. But I have found a solution for backward compability to ellipsize the string and create `StaticLayout` until `lineCount` return needed value.

```
fun createStaticLayout(text: String, textWidth: Int, maxLines: Int, paint: TextPaint): StaticLayout =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        StaticLayout.Builder
            .obtain(text, 0, text.length, paint, textWidth)
            .setAlignment(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL)
            .setMaxLines(maxLines)
            .setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)
            .build()
    } else {
        var layout: StaticLayout? = null
        var maxLength: Int = min(text.length, 200) // Could be adjusted

        do {
            layout = StaticLayout(
                text.ellipsize(maxLength), paint, textWidth,
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1f, 0f,
                false
            )
            maxLength -= 10
        } while (layout!!.lineCount > maxLines)

        layout
    }

///.....

fun String.ellipsize(
    size: Int,
    ending: Char? = '…'
): String = if (this.isEmpty() || size <= 0) {
    ""
} else if (length <= size) {
    this
} else {
    this.substring(0, max(size - 1, 0)).let {
        if (ending == null) {
            it
        } else {
            it + ending
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was using Reflection to get access the fourth constructor which accepts to set `maxLines` in the last parameter and it works for me:

```
try {
                Constructor<StaticLayout> constructor = StaticLayout.class.getConstructor(
                        CharSequence.class, int.class, int.class, TextPaint.class, int.class,
                        Layout.Alignment.class, TextDirectionHeuristic.class, float.class, float.class,
                        boolean.class, TextUtils.TruncateAt.class, int.class, int.class
                );
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
                StaticLayout sl = constructor.newInstance(text, 0, text.length(), textPaint, width,
                        aligment, TextDirectionHeuristics.FIRSTSTRONG_LTR, spacingMult, spacingAdd,
                        includePad, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END, width, maxLines);

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException exception) {
                Log.d("TAG_APP", Log.getStackTraceString(exception));
            }
```